# HowTo Google Sign-In - Understanding, Security - What to do with the data

Tags: javascript, google-signin

i am having problems understanding how to use "Google Sign-In" in a secure way.
I am adding the script to my Website. After that i call google.accounts.id.initialize.

```
google.accounts.id.initialize( {
    client_id: googleClientId,
    callback: handleCredentialResponse,
    native_callback: handlePassword,
    context: 'signin'
} );
```

After that i am getting the response with this code:

```
function parseJwt( token ) {
    var base64Url = token.split( '.' )[ 1 ];
    var base64 = base64Url.replace( /-/g, '+' ).replace( /_/g, '/' );
    var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent( atob( base64 ).split( '' ).map( function( c ) {
        return '%' + ( '00' + c.charCodeAt( 0 ).toString( 16 ) ).slice( -2 );
    } ).join( '' ) );
    return JSON.parse( jsonPayload );
};


function handleCredentialResponse( obj ) {
    const responsePayload = parseJwt( obj.credential );
    console.log( "OBJECT: " + JSON.stringify( responsePayload ) );
    console.log( "ID: " + responsePayload.sub );
    console.log( 'Full Name: ' + responsePayload.name );
    console.log( 'Given Name: ' + responsePayload.given_name );
    console.log( 'Family Name: ' + responsePayload.family_name );
    console.log( "Image URL: " + responsePayload.picture );
    console.log( "Email: " + responsePayload.email );
}
```

The response looks like this:

```
{
    "iss":"https://accounts.google.com",
    "nbf":00000000000,
    "aud":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "sub":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "email":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@googlemail.com",
    "email_verified":true,
    "azp":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "name":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "picture":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "given_name":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "iat":00000000000,
    "exp":00000000000,
    "jti":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

So far, so good. But now? The Google-Documentation is not covering explanations for all those variables. I do not understand what to do now with this data? I could sent it to my server and then create a new user if not already exist by using the unique id "sub". But how, without password? I havent found any explanation in the web or the docs.

Comment: If you trusted this kind of data being send from the client - then anyone could send you whatever fake data they like. You should send only the token to the server, and then make an API request from there, to get all the other details.

Comment: _"But how, without password?"_ - the _point_ of using such an external auth provider is, that users won't _need_ a specific password for your site any more ... You get the token, you request user details from the API with it. Using those, you go look up the data stored in your database (usually using a unique ID provided by the auth provider), and if you find a matching user - then you consider them as successfully authenticated and therefor "logged in" from there on.

Comment: Most of the variables in your response are part of the `JWT` web standard, so it's logical that Google doesn't document them, you can find the specification here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1 However, Google has decent instructions on how to securely implement Google Sign in here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth (including tips on what to do with the `sub`, `iss` etc fields)

Comment: Thank you. For what i ve understood now i have to sent the credential to my backend and verify it there. If token is verified and user does not exists -> create and login, if exists and valid only login otherwise deny.

Comment: $client = new \Google_Client(['client_id' => $arrFromIni['google']['clientId']]);
   $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($token);

Thats where i am now. If the $payload is not empty, the token is valid:
But why do i not need to use my secret?!

Comment: Can anyone please try to add <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" crossorigin="anonymous" async=""></script> to firefox?
Inside Firefox i am getting a 403 forbidden, in Chrome it works.

Comment: The reason you do not need a secret is that the JWT is not encrypted. During JWT verification you are checking if the JWT was created, issued and sent by Google. Only Google has the private key for signing, you use the public key provided by Google to confirm the corresponding private key signed the JWT.

Comment: Second reason a client secret is unnecessary, authorized JavaScript origins in your OAuth2 settings in the developer console. HTTPS and it's certs are used to verify the origin.  Since web pages are public, including a secret within one means it is no longer a secret.

Comment: Has anyone an idea how i could react if someone is not logged in by Google? The script does not load in this case. I am getting a 403 forbidden. For not logged in Users (at Google) i want then to redirect them to Google to sign in there first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comments, reading and thinking further i am now having a solution which works, but needs some "tweaking".

The answer to my own question is:

I have to send the credential response to my backend/server.

```
google.accounts.id.initialize( {
    client_id: googleClientId,
    callback: handleCredentialResponse,//this function!
    context: 'signin'
} );

function handleCredentialResponse( obj ) {
const r = await Master.newXhrPostRequest( {
    url: '/xhr',
    mode: 'signInWithGoogle',
    credential: obj.credential//this!
} );
```

after sending it to my own backend/server i have to verify that this is valid. for this i could write my own verifier, but that is not recommended.
In my case for PHP i had to use this:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

There are other APIs for Java, Node, Go, Ruby, Python, etc. here:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library

this looks like so

```
require_once ROOT_PATH . "php/src/google-api-php-client--PHP8.0/vendor/autoload.php";
$client = new \Google_Client(['client_id' => 'YOUR CLIENT ID YOU SET UP IN THE GOOGLE API BACKEND FOR THAT APP']);
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($token);

if ($payload) {
    //verified -> continue /signin/register with the data
} else {
    //not verified -> error
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The JWT should be verified on your back-end server. Browsers are not a secure environment and run on the users machine which is itself out of your control. Presumably a back end server you host has **much** higher levels of security.

This [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token) has details on how to confirm that the JWT was issued by Google and is still valid. Cross Site Request Forgery (CRSF) is also discussed.

Ideally, you will host and use a [login end-point](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference?hl=en#data-login_uri) instead of using a JS handler to forward the JWT to your back-end. This skips the insecure environment on the user's browser and enables your OAuth2 Client ID's Authorized redirect URL settings to help authenticate your endpoints.

Lastly, you'll want to include a [nonce](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference?#nonce). Generating a nonce for each request is highly recommended. You then confirm that the unique nonce is receieved as a field in the JWT returned by Google. Doing so helps to prevent replay attacks.

In summary, generate a nonce per sign in request, setup and configure a login end-pint to receive the JWT, then verify both the JWT and the nonce on your back-end.